# How do I dynamically change GridOptions in ag-grid React, specifically go from a tree to a non-tree model?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using version ag-grid 21.2.2 with React 16.11

In ag-grid, some GridOptions appear to be fixed after initialization.  Of these fixed options, some options can be changed using an api call, like setColumnDefs(), possibly setServerSideDatasource() (though I haven't tried that)

My immediate problem is: I would like to be able to switch between a "serverSide"/treeData config and a "serverSide"/non-tree data config.  It doesn't work for me when I pass in different GridOptions to the React component and I see no way to do that using the API.

Comment: Please add more details like code.